# Can I play audio on my speakers and headset at the same time?

Tags: audio, speakers

I was wondering if it is possible to use both my speakers and headset at the same time, but for different programs. For example, I would like my headset to be on skype, but i'd also like my speakers playing music from Spotify.

I currently have my headset plugged into a laptop with built in speakers and I have had a problem in the past where the headset and speakers were both playing audio at the same time. The difference is that I want them to play different audios this time around.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please elaborate, what OS are you using? What connector does the headset have? I can attest that this is possible, I play online games with sound output on internal speakers while using a headset with skype/teamspeak.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. My headset is simply plugged into my laptop with the green and the pink jack on the side.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you are using 3.5mm jacks, it means that both speakers and headset are using the same output device. Depending on how it is wired, your system might not be able to detect if it is using your headset or speakers for output, as they are the same audio device for the OS. There might be some ways around this using virtual audio devices. I am using an USB based headset which registers itself as a separate device. You can define the output here per-app, which is what you are looking for. Maybe consider getting one.

Comment: I do have Steelseries 7H headset, which comes with a USB Soundcard. Would this suffice? Where exactly can I go to define output per app, is that in the software for the headset?

Comment: Most programs that use sound have a way to select a card. Per example, if you open skype settings, you will be able to use the input and output sound device for skype. If you select your usb sound card there, your normal system sounds (eg. spotify) will play back using your speakers, while skype will only use your usb device. Otherwise play around with the mixer settings in windows :)